# Android media player in a service keeps causing ANR

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

I have a service that is supposed to stream audio using a media player the streaming happens fine but seems to happen in the UI thread even though am using AsyncTask

**sample Code **

```
package com.package.app;


import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Mplayer extends Service {
    static boolean isPlaying = false;
    public MediaPlayer mp;
    String url = null;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent paramIntent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        isPlaying = false;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music stopping", 1).show();

        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        isPlaying = false;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent paramIntent, int paramInt) {
        super.onStart(paramIntent, paramInt);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Getting the Best", 1).show();
        url = ((String) paramIntent.getExtras().getString("url"));

        play p = new play();
        p.execute();


    }


    public class play extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setAudioStreamType(3);
            Log.v("service", "starting jobo");


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Log.v("service", url);
                mp.setDataSource(url);
                Log.v("service", "datasourse set");
                mp.prepareAsync();

                Log.v("service", "prepared");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("serviceError", e.toString());

            }

            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {

                    Log.v("service","going in ");
                    player.getDuration();
                    player.start();
                    Log.v("duration", player.getDuration()+" ");
                    for(int i=0; i<player.getDuration(); player.getCurrentPosition())
                    {
                        //Log.v("position", "pos"+player.getCurrentPosition());
                    }


                    Log.v("service", "playing");

                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            int n = values[0];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), n+" time ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}
```

this code causes an ANR error please

Comment: Don't use an Asynctask for that, it's not needed. The MediaPlayer has a prepareAsync method that will return a callback when it's ready. You're already using it, but remember the MediaPlayer handles it's own threading. (The service, however, runs on the Main Thread together with the UI).